# How to pass self into a decorator?

Tags: python, python-2.7

How do I pass `self.key` below into the decorator?

```
class CacheMix(object):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CacheMix, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    key_func = Constructor(
        memoize_for_request=True,
        params={'updated_at': self.key}
    )

    @cache_response(key_func=key_func)
    def list(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass

class ListView(CacheMix, generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    key = 'test_key'
```

I get the error:

```
'self' is not defined
```

Comment: There's no `self` doesn't at the time class object is being created, re-think your approach and also fix the indentation.

Comment: If you showed the code for the decorator it would help — as would knowing what statement is causing the error message.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary if thats the case anyway to create the decorator in the init? i.e.  ``self.list = cache_response(key_func)(type(self).list)``

Comment: The decorator is here @martineau https://github.com/chibisov/drf-extensions/blob/master/rest_framework_extensions/cache/decorators.py

Comment: You might be able to do it with a class decorator since that the kind of attribute the `self.key` you're using is really referring to (as opposed to an instance attribute).

Comment: @martineau Can you give me an example :)

Comment: A class decorator is like a function decorator except its argument is a class instead of a function and it returns a class (usually a modified version of the one it was passed). Seems like you could make one that used the value of the decorated class's `key` attribute in conjuction with the existing `cache_response` decorator you have and applied it to the `list` method.

Comment: @martineau I kinda understand not should how if could be used  in conjunction with the existing cache_response decorator tho. An example would really help if you have time. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example of doing it with a class decorator as I tried to describe to you in the comments. I filled-in a few undefined references in your question and used a super-simplified version of your `cache_response` function decorator, but hopefully this will convey the idea concretely enough for you to be able adapt it to your real code.

```
import inspect
import types

class Constructor(object):
    def __init__(self, memoize_for_request=True, params=None):
        self.memoize_for_request = memoize_for_request
        self.params = params
    def __call__(self):
        def key_func():
            print('key_func called with params:')
            for k, v in self.params.items():
                print('  {}: {!r}'.format(k, v))
        key_func()

def cache_response(key_func):
    def decorator(fn):
        def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
            key_func()
            fn(*args, **kwargs)
        return decorated
    return decorator

def example_class_decorator(cls):
    key_func = Constructor(  # define key_func here using cls.key
        memoize_for_request=True,
        params={'updated_at': cls.key} # use decorated class's attribute
    )
    # create and apply cache_response decorator to marked methods
    # (in Python 3 use types.FunctionType instead of types.UnboundMethodType)
    decorator = cache_response(key_func)
    for name, fn in inspect.getmembers(cls):
        if isinstance(fn, types.UnboundMethodType) and hasattr(fn, 'marked'):
            setattr(cls, name, decorator(fn))
    return cls

def decorate_me(fn):
    setattr(fn, 'marked', 1)
    return fn

class CacheMix(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CacheMix, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    @decorate_me
    def list(self, *args, **kwargs):
        classname = self.__class__.__name__
        print('list() method of {} object called'.format(classname))

@example_class_decorator
class ListView(CacheMix):
    key = 'test_key'

listview = ListView()
listview.list()
```

Output:

```
key_func called with params:
  updated_at: 'test_key'
list() method of ListView object called
```

Answer (score 2):

I just found out that if you write the decorator function like so:

```
def decorator(the_func):
    @wraps(the_func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        the_func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

and decorate any method which takes self as an argument, self will appear in args. Therefore you can do this:

```
from functools import wraps
class myClass:

    def __init__(self):
        self.myValue = "Hello"

    def decorator(the_func):     
        @wraps(the_func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            print(args[0].myValue)
            the_func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper    

    @decorator
    def myFunction(self):
        print("World")
```

Call it like you normally would

```
foo = myClass()
foo.myFunction()
```

and you should get

```
Hello
World
```