# NoneType object is not callable on class defined decorator

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators, nonetype

I have an oddly specific issue related to the overarching `NoneType` object issues that are frequently found on SE. I am attempting to use a decorator function to open a file while the decorated functions applies specific operations that are file type specific (aka text, rich text, PDF, etc.)

The process parses fine, and works through object creation and class initialization, but throws the exception when I try to call the `PDFReader` function which currently only has a debug print statement of `"Reached"`.

I have found that it is due to the double defined method I am using as the function call seems to be in the parent function where the actual parameters I am trying to access can only be used in the child function.

My question is: If I wish to have a class bound decorator that uses the object's initialized variables via `self`, how can I fix my code or is there a better way to achieve what I am trying?

Filehandler.py:

```
class Fileloader(object):

    class _decorators():
        @classmethod
        def _reader(cls, decorated):
            print('File opened in Read-Only Mode')
             #---No error if "decorated()" called here.

            def decorator(self, *args, **kwargs):
                print(self._file) #---Prints to console then throws the exception
                decorated(self, *args, **kwargs)
                ...


    def __init__(self, filename, mode='rb'):
        self._file = filename
        self._mode = mode
        print(self._file)

    @_decorators._reader
    def pdfReader(self):
        print("reached") #---never reached
        ...


Test = Fileloader('test.pdf')
Test.pdfReader()
```

Comment: What error are you getting? What does `_reader` return? Presumably it is returning `None` which your erroreaaage suggests

Comment: Decorators, regardless of whether they're implemented as a function or class, must ultimately return something callable — and I don't see that in your code. To be more concrete, the `_reader()` method doesn't return the nested `decorator()` function (it returns `None` which is of type `NoneType`).

Comment: My answer to [How to pass self into a decorator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33593846/how-to-pass-self-into-a-decorator) might offer some insights wrt to your goal.

Answer (score 0):

Super easy fix, I just was staring at the code for to long to see it.

Thanks @martineau for pointing out that my outer decorator does not return anything.

The fixed code is as so

```
class Fileloader(object):
    class _decorators():
        @classmethod
        def _reader(cls, decorated):
            print('File opened in Read-Only Mode')

            def decorator(self, *args, **kwargs):
                print(self._file)
                with open(self._file, mode=self._mode) as self.f:
                    print('Decorator')
                    decorated(self, *args, **kwargs)
                    pass

            return decorator #<----- Added this and it works as it should
```

edit: For any of those after me that need an explanation of what happened, I made an inner class `class _decorators()` to allow the use of a nested function (`@classmethod def_reader(cls, decorated)` which takes the required parameters of `cls` (short for class) and `decorated` (which is the keyword I used for the function passed). Then an inner function is defined so that I have access to the `self` dictionary of that object, this is done due to how Python works.

Python will first parse through a portion of the code, so if I only had the inner function `decorator` then it would pass an exception as at this time there is no `self` attribute.

After it initializes the object via `Test = Fileloader('test.pdf')` then it **DOES** have a `self` attribute that can be accessed by the inner function `decorator` at runtime. Hence the need for a nested function as the parser will pass by the inner function during parsetime but will come back and read it during runtime when the object is instantiated.